# How to speed up Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, performance, system

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and my system is too much slow, I want to speed it up. I have tried several apps and methods like `jupitar`, cleaning tmp file, but still my system is too much slow.

Here is my sys config: `1gb RAM` `160gb hdd` `intel duo core`

Answer (score 1):

Try using LXDE. It is lighter than Unity (the default DE) and will speed up your computer.

For 12.04 and later versions, you'll need to do this through a terminal.

Open up a terminal (<kbd>Super</kbd>, then type `Terminal` into the dash), then run the following:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`

Or install via the Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

You will get asked to enter your password, and you will also be asked to choose between `LightDM` and `LXDM` - I suggest using `LightDM`.

Once that is done, log out, and then select `Lubuntu` as your desktop session:

[image]

Comment: what is the difference betweem lxdm and lightdm

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up your ubuntu system using this 4 triks. It might be useful to you:

[4 Tricks to speed Up Ubuntu 14.X - I am Programmer](http://www.improgrammer.net/4-tricks-speed-up-ubuntu-14-x/)