# How do speed up ubuntu 12.0.4 on virtualbox 5.1.2 by getting a lighter DE?

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, lxde

hope you can help me.

I've been setting up for flask development in Ubuntu on a VM on Windows Vista (old, but outside the VM works fine). I've tried most the Ram tweaks for the VM platform (Virtualbox).

The terminal commands/downloads work at good speed but navigation and folder browsing etc is quite slow.

I've been looking to speed it up and there are many tweaks available online but 1 not sure if they'll result in much performance improvement 2 they are all quite time-consuming to implement.

What I'm looking for is a bare bones, no-nice effects version of the OS purely for dev work. Even and old Dos style setup would be fine, with no packages/programs not relevant to dev work.

- q1 Would I lose all my work (packages installation (pip, node, flask,
  npm, venvwrapper, bootstrap, my app itself) if I switch?
- q2 Will the
  switch result in faster performance but not exclude/hider dev work?
- q3 If I do switch, how long would it take and which should I go for, 
  I'm new to the platform so excuse my lack of knowledge:

  **A-** No desktop https://askubuntu.com/a/413879

  **B-** (Seems like right option) Lubuntu with XDE/ just install LXDE as mentioned here https://askubuntu.com/a/367369/578534. The only reasons I'm asking a new question is that I'm unsure of what will happen to my old changes/updates in this event

  **C-** Continue with ubuntu and keep using the tweaks (such as disabling 3D      effects, changing RAM allocating/swap rate)

My priority is time and I would rather not spend hours installing/downloading/modifying. Also keeping the changes/installs I have made to Ubuntu would be semi-necessary (depending how much performance improvements the new setup would offer). Current version is tolerable so might just continue with that.

Help is much appreciated, I'm new to the platform and have heard the community is very helpful so thought I'd ask for assistance.

Many thanks

edit: LXDE seems like a simple install that would give immediate benefits. Also no desktop would seems like a quick effective fix. Trying to keep out of the weeds of complicated/time-consuming changes! Hoping for a quick fix (unsurprisingly).

Answer (score 0):

I have installed xfce4 alongside Unity and do not have any problems. All software works in both desktop environments (running steam games for example).

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Switching between unity and xfce4 is done on login screen.

Only problem I had there was no unity notifications after xfce4 install so I had to uninstall xfce4-notifyd package

```
sudo apt-get remove xfce4-notifyd
```